# Jquery Dot Navigation within Drop Down Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a parallax portfolio site and want to include some jquery features. Currently I have a working drop down gallery but I am wanting to add a dot navigation to the gallery. Once I added the dot navigation, the drop down feature stopped working. I have set up an example on jsfiddle. The first link, shows the drop down feature. (Currently opens up every gallery at the same time.) The second link adds the dot navigation.

http://jsfiddle.net/carincamen/pvphpcuw/12/

HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<p>Click the small black box to show the large rectangle box.</p>

<img class="arrow"> 

<div class="gallery"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.gallery {
    position: relative;
    width: 620px;
    height: 215px;
    top: 30px;
    left: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}

.arrow{
    position: relative;
    width:20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 15px;
    left: 340px;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var display =$('.gallery');
  $(display).hide();
  $('.arrow').click(function(){
    $(display).toggle();
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/carincamen/pvphpcuw/

For ease of demonstration I have color coded the dot navigation buttons to correspond with the slides.

Thank you in advance for your assistance. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A special thank you for a LinkedIn group memeber who was prompt to take a look. The gallery drops down when clicking the arrow, then the navigation buttons change out the sliders. The small navigation buttons increase and decrease with opacity depending on their corresponding slider, and the large circle moves to the dot navigation that corresponds with the slider. The working code can be found [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/carincamen/pvphpcuw). Hope this is helpful.

I needed to remove the `$(this).next` and just use `$` and then add `$("[class^=gallery]").hide()` to remove the previous gallery.